# Как подсчитать значения арифметических операторов при $a и $b рандомных числах?

Tags: php, html, css

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Необходимо вывести таблицу арифметических операций языка программирования PHP для переменных, значения которых задаются случайным образом.

Условием является то, что таблицу оформить надо с помощью HTML и CSS, а PHP - только для обработки переменных. 
Вот пример есть, пишу в notepad++, но при загрузке .php файла через firefox, обработка переменных не происходит.
[image: Пример]

```
  <html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <head>
  <title>Лаб</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1> Лабораторная работа №1 </h1>
 <h2> Задание 1 </h2>
 Переменные:
 <p>$a = rand</p>
 <p>$b= rand </p>
 <h4> Арифметические операторы </h4>
 <table border="1">
<tr>
<td>Оператор</td>
<td>Название</td>
<td> Пример</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>-$a</td>
<td>Смена знака</td>
<td> <?php $str = "Число" . $a . "При смене знака <br>". "равно" . -$a;
echo $str; ?></td>
<tr> <td>$a + $b</td>
<td>Сложение</td>
<td> <?php $a . "плюс. <br>". "равно" . ;
echo ($a + $b)."\n"; ?></td></tr>
<tr> <td>$a - $b</td>
<td>Вычитание</td>
<td> <?php $str = "Число" . $a . "При смене знака <br>". "равно" . -$a;
echo $str; ?></td></tr>
<tr> <td>$a * $b</td>
<td>Умножение</td>
<td> <?php $str = "Число" . $a . "При смене знака <br>". "равно" . -$a;
echo $str; ?></td></tr>
<tr> <td>$a / $b</td>
<td>Деление</td>
<td> <?php $str = "Число" . $a . "При смене знака <br>". "равно" . -$a;
echo $str; ?></td></tr>
<tr> <td>$a % $b</td>
<td>Деление по модулю</td>
<td> <?php $str = "Число" . $a . "При смене знака <br>". "равно" . -$a;
echo $str; ?></td></tr>
<tr> <td>$a ** $b</td>
<td>Возведение в степень</td>
<td> <?php $str = "Число" . $a . "При смене знака <br>". "равно" . -$a;
echo $str; ?></td></tr>
</tr>
</table> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Выложите ваш код.

Comment: Выложил. Не понимаю совсем, как заставить работать рандомные переменные

Answer (score 0):

PHP является серверным языком веб-программирования. Для запуска php скриптов нужен интерпретатор php. Можно установить локальный сервер на подобии [denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/) или [Open Server](https://ospanel.io/). Либо запускать с помощью непосредственно интерпретатора [Выполнение PHP-файлов](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.usage.php)

```
$ php my_script.php
```

Comment: Денвер стоит, но при этом ничего не происходит

Comment: в начале страницы надо добавить инициализацию переменных $a и $b `<?php
$a = rand();
$b = rand();
?>`

Comment: не надо denver'ов и openserver'ов rпросто в консоле `php -S localhost:8080 myScript.php`  и в браузере `localhost:8080`